Nextjs 14 chunks not loading in prod build
I have a nextjs 14 application which I need to deploy to k8s. We've built a docker image from nextjs docs and deployed it to our DO cluster.
When trying to access the application, some chunks are not loaded. Nginx logs indicate that nextjs app container refuses the connection:
[error] 2966#2966: *9700114 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.100.0.5, server: staging.vooz.co, request: "GET /_next/static/chunks/app/terms-of-service/page-3c6db42ee349bf99.js H ││ TTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.244.1.68:7531/_next/static/chunks/app/terms-of-service/page-3c6db42ee349bf99.js", host: "staging.vooz.co", referrer: "https://staging.vooz.co/"

I watched the tutorial by NextJS dev rel but didn't find any obvious solution (aside that he was using version 15).
Did anyone face this issue before?
Dockerfile for reference:
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the presence of package-lock.json
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 7531

ENV PORT=7531

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
ENV HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0"
CMD ["node", "server.js"]

